# what's the better way to concat several strings in C

Tags: c, linux, macros

I want to concat several strings in c using macro, what I did is :

```
#define PROCESS_NAME         "process_a"

#ifdef WITH_PID_FILE
#define PROCESS_PID          "-p /tmp/process_a.pid"
#else
#define PROCESS_PID          ""
#endif

#define PROCESS_CMD          PROCESS_NAME" -i %s -a %s "PROCESS_PID" &"
```

but it looks really awful, is there any better way?

my goal is to use PROCESS_CMD in snprintf and perform system call

Comment: This produces `"process_a"" -i %s -a %s ""-p /tmp/process_a.pid"" &"`. Do you really need the `"` marks?

Comment: @Dipto: After the preprocessor combines adjacent string literals, that becomes `"process_a -i %s -a %s -p /tmp/process_a.pid &"`  Seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the `macros` are fixed and won't change and you'll use them in several locations then this is fine.
Yet, using a macro in `snprintf` may make the command less readable and less obvious at first glance.

Have a look [here](http://c-faq.com/cpp/index.html) about the usage of macros.